# Find a good heuristic for the following problem(A*)

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics

I am trying to find a heuristic function for the following problem. You are given n buckets of paint with maximum capacity max_i,current capacity curr_i and the colour of the painting colour_i, i = 1,n and a list o possible combinations of colours: col1 + col2 -> col3. The final state of the problem is a set of pairs (quantity,colour) which have to be found in the buckets #(final_state) <= no. of buckets.

The goal is to mix those buckets such as in the end, each pair from the final state is found in at least one bucket. At each move, you can pour from one bucket into another if the bucket you are pouring in is not full.

The problem is that I cannot think of a classic heuristic to fit this problem as I am not able to compare the buckets from the initial state with those from the final state(it's not an unique). Does the heuristic have to be the numbers of moves from the current state to the final one or can it be some number that decreases as we approach the scope ?

Answer (score 0):

The heuristic has to be [admissible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), so it should not underestimate the actual distance. As you come closer to the goal, it should in principle be more precise, and thus could suddenly get smaller more quickly. But that is perfectly fine, as long as it's not underestimating.

As the distance to the goal is generally the number of moves, it is hard to see how it can be something completely unrelated. So, yes, the heuristic ought to be related to the number of moves, but doesn't have to, as long as it is pessimistic rather than optimistic.